# Python Flask infinite loop use global list which can be extended

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I would like to run an infinite loop in flask, which do something with a global list.
I'd like to append the list through an API call, and process data from the updated list.
What is the problem?

Usage: you run flask application, and call localhost:5000/ to append the list.
It will return the new list, but in the loop, it remains the initial list.

Thanks

```py
import time
from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

app = Flask(__name__)

stuff = [1, 2]


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    global stuff
    stuff.append(max(stuff) + 1)
    print('in request, stuff: ', stuff)
    return ', '.join(map(str, stuff))


def print_stuff():
    global stuff
    print('in loop, stuff: ', stuff)


def record_loop(loop_on):
    while True:
        if loop_on.value == True:
            print_stuff()
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    recording_on = Value('b', True)
    p = Process(target=record_loop, args=(recording_on,))
    p.start()
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
    p.join()
```

Comment: try starting only one Flask app instance.

Comment: Why can't you just create a global object, accessible from all endpoints and append to it? Something in a form of a database. If particular endpoint is hit, some value is appended to the global list you earlier declared, and the list is returned for that request. Also, if you would like to have some kind of parallelized code, you may have a look at fastAPI - it has basically same syntax as Flask, but supports async methods

Comment: Thank you!
@PrzemysławSamsel I'd like to use flask because the other part of my code is in Flask.

Comment: @keremistan how can I do that exactly? Could you send a code snippet?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the working solution:

```
import time

from flask import Flask
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler

app = Flask(__name__)
scheduler = APScheduler()

i = 0

def scheduleTask():
    global i
    print("This test runs every 1 seconds", i)
    time.sleep(2)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    global i
    i += 1
    return str(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler.add_job(id = 'Scheduled Task', func=scheduleTask, trigger="interval", seconds=1)
    scheduler.start()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```